Have I Found a New Refutation of the Kalam Cosmological Argument, or Am I Missing Something?
I’ve been thinking about the Kalam Cosmological Argument (KCA) lately, and I think I might have come up with a refutation I haven’t seen before. I’ve searched around online, but I can’t find anyone making this exact argument. So, I figured I’d share it here to see if it’s actually a solid critique or if I’m missing something important. Let me know what you think!
For those unfamiliar, the Kalam goes like this:


Whatever begins to exist has a cause.
The universe began to exist.
Therefore, the universe has a cause.


Now, let’s focus specifically on the definitions KCA proponents (like William Lane Craig) use, because that’s where the problem starts.
The Definition of the Universe
Craig defines the universe as:

All of space-time reality, including all matter and energy.

In simple terms, the universe is everything that physically exists. It’s the set of everything that exists physically, which includes all space, time, matter, energy—basically everything real in any place or time. Nothing physical exists outside of this set.
On “Whatever Begins to Exist”
KCA proponents also claim that everything in the universe began to exist. While some might argue against this (e.g., by saying the universe is eternal or there are multiple universes), I’ll cede this point for the sake of argument:

Everything that physically exists began to exist.
There’s nothing physical that exists which didn’t begin to exist.

Two Identical Sets
Let’s examine two sets that arise from these claims:
The first set is everything that physically exists. By definition, this set is the universe. It contains all matter, energy, space, and time, and excludes nothing physical.
The second set is everything that began to physically exist. This set, according to KCA proponents, also includes all matter, energy, space, and time—because everything physical began to exist.
At first glance, it might seem like the equivalence of these sets is obvious, but let’s spell it out in both directions:

Everything that physically exists (the universe) began to exist.
This is conceded in the KCA. Every star, galaxy, particle, and even space-time itself began to exist, so the entire set of everything that physically exists falls under “things that began to exist.”

Everything that began to exist physically exists (and is part of the universe).
If something began to exist, it is by definition something physical—it exists in space and time as matter or energy, or it is part of the space-time framework itself. And since Craig’s definition of the universe is “all space-time reality, including all matter and energy,” this means that anything that began to exist is necessarily part of the universe.


Thus, the set of “everything that physically exists” and the set of “everything that began to exist” are perfectly identical. They include the same members and exclude the same members. This means they are interchangeable.
The Problem for the KCA
Now let’s revisit the KCA’s first premise:

Whatever begins to exist has a cause.

Because the set of “everything that begins to exist” is identical to the set of “everything that physically exists” (the universe), we can restate this premise as:

The universe has a cause.

See the issue? The first premise is now just a reformulation of the conclusion. The argument is no longer a valid deduction—it’s just circular reasoning. The KCA assumes what it’s trying to prove.
When you break it down like this, the KCA doesn’t really demonstrate that the universe has a cause; it just rewords the conclusion into the first premise.
Why This Works
The problem arises from the way the KCA defines its terms. If the universe is simply the set of all things that physically exist, and all those things began to exist, then the first premise and the conclusion are functionally the same. This makes the KCA invalid because circular arguments don’t prove anything.
Possible Objections
Now, I can anticipate a couple of counterarguments from KCA proponents, but I don’t think they hold up:

“The universe is more than just the set of its contents.”
Some might argue that the universe is a distinct entity that’s separate from the set of its contents. But this doesn’t work because Craig defines the universe as all space, time, matter, and energy—meaning the universe is nothing more than the sum of its parts. There’s no extra “thing” beyond its contents.

“The first premise is a general causal principle.”
Proponents might say that the first premise (“Whatever begins to exist has a cause”) is based on observations within the universe and can be applied to the universe as a whole. But here’s the problem: if the universe is just the set of all things that began to exist, applying the causal principle to the universe is assuming the conclusion.


Final Thoughts
So, what do you all think? Am I on to something here? By sticking to the definitions that KCA proponents like Craig use, I think I’ve shown that the argument collapses into circular reasoning. If the universe is just the set of everything that physically exists, and everything that exists began to exist, then the first premise and the conclusion are basically the same. That makes the KCA invalid.
Have you seen this argument before? Am I missing something obvious? Let me know what you think!

Even assuming that  the set of “everything that begins to exist” = the universe, "the universe has a cause” is not a restatement of “whatever begins to exist has a cause”. The first is a statement about a set and the second about its elements (presumably), equating the two is the fallacy of composition/division. Also, your explication seems to make the universe its own element which traditional sets cannot do. Surmising 'general causal principle' from instances is just induction. Applying it then to another instance is not formally valid, of course, and open to dispute, but not circular.

“The universe begins to exist” does not equal to “everything in the universe begins to exist”, simply because what applies to each particular thing in the universe does not have to apply to the entire group.

Thanks for engaging! Let me clarify.


Composition/Division Fallacy: I’m not equating a set with its elements. My argument is that Craig defines “the universe” as the set of all things that begin to exist. This makes the first premise (“whatever begins to exist has a cause”) interchangeable with the conclusion (“the universe has a cause”), leading to circularity.


Universe as Its Own Element: I’m not claiming the universe is an element of itself. The universe, per Craig, is the set of all things that began to exist—there’s no “extra” universe beyond this set.



@TonyMcKracken “My argument is that Craig defines “the universe” as the set of all things that begin to exist.” He doesn’t. He defines the universe as the set of all physical things. Your inference would work if what applies to each element in a set also applies to the set. But it doesn’t. Imagine I define a word Hall = the set of all blue balls. This does not imply that Hall is blue

@Syed If he defines the universe as the set of all physical things and then says in premise 2 that the universe began to exist, he is saying that the set of all physical things began to exist, no? And if the universe is the set of all physical things and all physical things began to exist (his argument), then the set of all physical things that began to exist is equal to the set of all physical things (the universe). Therefore, “whatever began to exist has a cause” is the same as “the universe has a cause.” Which means that the first premise is equal to the conclusion.

Just replace "cause" with "physical cause" or "cause within the universe", and now you've got an equally well-supported argument against the existence of an external non-physical creator. We have no verified examples of non-physical causes (although some might disagree with that), so it's questionable to generalise "cause" to include that, for the purposes of then immediately concluding that there is such a cause, based on that generalisation.

Words like "whatever" and "universe" along with OP's definition of "universe" as the mereological whole of all its components, such argument should be analyzed in terms of FOL instead in propositional logic with Modus Ponens. Then like ZFC/NBG/MK set theories, the whole of all parts cannot be a part thus your first premise can only apply to all parts but not the whole and your conclusion is blocked. Similarly in category theory you can have a large set aka Grothendieck universe U of sets of inaccessible cardinality, but a single quantifier of sets still cannot range over U itself...

@DoubleKnot, I’m not committing the composition fallacy because my argument doesn’t reason from the parts of the universe to the whole (or vice versa). Instead, I’m pointing out that Craig’s own definitions make the universe (the set of all things that physically exist) identical to the set of “everything that begins to exist.” Because these sets are interchangeable, the first premise (“whatever begins to exist has a cause”) and the conclusion (“the universe has a cause”) are equivalent, resulting in circular reasoning. My critique focuses on definitional equivalence, not composition.

@TonyMcKracken Your intuition is more or less on the right track. Strictly speaking in FOL, Craig's critical mereological definition of the "universe" as the absolute whole is subtly different from 'whatever' in his premise 1 since we can only observe whatever part of the universe which begins to exist has a cause as echoed by the famous principle of sufficient reason. Therefore the sense of his conclusion 3 is not the same as premise 1 as you pointed out, but actually the fallacy of a category error...

@DoubleKnot I’d argue the distinction between “whatever” in premise 1 and “the universe” in conclusion 3 doesn’t hold under Craig’s definitions. Craig defines the universe as the totality of all space-time, matter, and energy. This means “whatever begins to exist” inherently includes the whole universe, making premise 1 and conclusion 3 interchangeable, resulting in circularity.
A category error might apply in other contexts, but it doesn’t address this circularity. Craig’s framing collapses the distinction between the universe and its contents, assuming the conclusion in the first premise.

@TonyMcKracken Of course with the unexamined unrestricted quantification loosely speaking you're right, I've already emphasized my above comment is only from a strict FOL perspective which all existing popular set-theoretic and category-theoretic math foundations including mereology don't support the Universe itself in their domain of discourse, together with the fact that limited human beings can only observer and apply PSR to whatever part of the universe...

Yeah, fair enough—if you apply actual logic to the Kalam, it kind of falls apart anyway. I was just pointing out one specific issue I noticed with Craig’s argument—the way ‘everything that begins to exist’ and ‘the universe’ basically collapse into the same thing, making it circular. I hadn’t seen that called out before, but, let’s be real, it’s hardly the only problem with the whole thing!

I vote to close this question because the questioner puts to discussion their own philosophical thoughts and asks the group for feedback.- In addition the questioner assumes the validity of some very general principles. History of philosophy did not show that these principles are helpful for a serious investigation of the question.

@TonyMcKracken I believe that when he says that the “universe” has a cause, what he really means is that all physical stuff at time t = 0 has a cause

In your definitions, as well as what you think the universe is please specify what you mean by existence. Is it what Einstein has determined to exist in his concept of spactime? Probably not, please clarify.

The universe isn't defined to be things that begin to exist, in Craig's Kalam argument. You say he defines it to be, "All of space-time reality, including all matter and energy." Nothing, at this point, has said that all of space-time reality began to exist. That comes in later, at premise 2, "the universe began to exist."
So you cannot replace premise 1, "Whatever begins to exist has a cause," with "the universe has a cause," unless you already have the equivalence of "the universe" and "whatever began to exist" - but you don't have that yet, that comes later, at premise 2.
Actually, technically speaking, premise 2 doesn't even say "whatever begins to exist" and "the universe" are equivalent; it is consistent with premise 2 that there could be things that begin to exist that are outside the universe.
Speaking more generally, it's not really a flaw in a formal argument that the conclusion is a rewording of the premises. That's true of any axiomatic system; anything you prove from the axioms is simply a rewording of the axioms. The problem of circularity only arises when the premises are not any easier to accept than the conclusion, which is typically a subjective matter.
The actual flaw in the Kalam argument is premise 1, "Whatever begins to exist has a cause." Why should that be true? Let t be our time variable and f(t) = log(t) (defined for t > 0). f "began to exist" after time 0, because it was undefined prior to that, but what caused it to exist at time 0? Or for that matter what caused it to have the value 1 at time 10? Nothing caused it; f is just an arbitrary function of time. Causation is a statistical regularity we happen to observe in our place and time in our universe, not some absolute law that all conceivable universes must obey. The universe might be any mathematical object at all, most of which do not have a sensible notion of causation.

I don't think I've read any of Craig's books but I assume that as a Christian, Craig believes in souls and other non-physical beings (i.e. Michael, Satan, etc) that began.

I’m aware that something could begin to exist outside the universe and not contradict premise 2, but this is not the argument Craig makes. He argues that anything that physically exists is part of the universe, making no exception for anything outside the universe, save the god he adheres to. But if the universe is the set of everything that exists, and that set began to exist, and nothing exists outside the universe (his argument), then the set of things that exist (universe) and the set of things that began to exist are the same. Therefore, the universe can be subbed into premise 1.

@TonyMcKracken "The universe can be subbed into premise 1" - yeah, so, if you combine premise 2 and premise 1 to obtain the conclusion, you have just... made a valid deduction. It is not a flaw in an argument that the conclusion can be obtained from the premises via a valid deduction.

My argument is that once you analyze Craig’s definitions, premise one and the conclusion are identical. Once we analyze his definitions and determine that the “set of all things that exist” (universe) and the “set of all things that began to exist” are the same (the universe is everything and the universe began to exist), the Kalam can be restated as: “The universe has a cause. The universe began to exist. The universe has a cause.” I’m not arguing that the conclusion follows the premises, I’m arguing that the conclusion is in the premises.

Premise 1 can apply in cases where Whatever begins to exist can be defined in other ways. It could be a cake. It could be a thought. It could be a societal behavior pattern. It could be the universe. You go wrong by redefining a vague term into a specific one. Replacing Whatever begins to exist with the universe is the rest of the syllogism, not premise 1.
Mr. Craig, by your own statements, does not do this. He defines the universe, not whatever begins to exist.
No, the error is that we don't know whether anything really begins to exist, much less the universe. But you're giving that up in this case.
